# Not able to Bind Params in Yii2 QueryBuilder

Tags: php, yii2

I am Not able to bind params in Yii2 Query Builder in `between` condition

```
$query=(new Query())
    ->select('*')
    ->from(CreditSettings::tableName())
    ->where(['between','minPrice',':min',':max'])->addParams([
                ':min' =>0,
                ':max' => 1111110
     ])->createCommand()->queryAll();
```

Getting Error As:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
>   The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `creditSettings` WHERE `minPrice` BETWEEN ':min' AND ':max'

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$query=(new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select('*')
            ->from(CreditSettings::tableName())
            ->where(' minPrice between :min AND :max ')->addParams([
                        ':min' =>10007,
                        ':max' => 10075
             ])->createCommand()->queryAll();
```

Comment: I have implement it as above. but want to know why my params binding is not happening as above.

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way:

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('minPrice', '0', '1111110');
    $result = ModelName::model()->findAll($criteria);

    dump($result);
```

Comment: Question is for yii2 not yii1